# OpenGL glDrawArrays slower then glBegin

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been playing with glDrawArrays in my function.

For some reason im dropping around 400fps when drawing with glDrawArrays.

Im calling my Print function 2000 times for testing.

Not really sure why because i thought glDrawArrays was ment to be the way to do this?

Here is the print function:

```
void Font::Print(const char* Text, int x, int y)
{
    int sLen, Loop;
    int Row, Col;
    float U, V, U1, V1;

    CurX = x;
    CurY = y;

    sLen = (int)strnlen(Text, BFG_MAXSTRING);


#ifdef ARRAYDRAW
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
#else
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
#endif

    for (Loop = 0; Loop != sLen; ++Loop)
    {
        Row = (Text[Loop] - Base) / RowPitch;
        Col = (Text[Loop] - Base) - Row * RowPitch;

        U = Col * ColFactor;
        V = Row * RowFactor;
        U1 = U + ColFactor;
        V1 = V + RowFactor;

#ifdef ARRAYDRAW
        Vertex vert[] = {
            CurX, CurY,
            U, V1,

            CurX + CellX, CurY,
            U1, V1,

            CurX + CellX, CurY + CellY,
            U1, V,

            CurX, CurY + CellY,
            U, V
        };

        glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(Vertex), &vert[0].x);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vert[0].u);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
#else
        glTexCoord2f(U, V1);  glVertex2i(CurX, CurY);
        glTexCoord2f(U1, V1);  glVertex2i(CurX + CellX, CurY);
        glTexCoord2f(U1, V); glVertex2i(CurX + CellX, CurY + CellY);
        glTexCoord2f(U, V); glVertex2i(CurX, CurY + CellY);
#endif


        CurX += Width[Text[Loop]];
    }

#ifdef ARRAYDRAW
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
#else
    glEnd();
#endi
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the main performance problems using OpenGL is the number of OpenGL calls. This is where `glDrawArrays` becomes handy: if you were rendering, say, a million triangles, it would be about a million calls of `glVertex` and similar, but still only a few calls using `glDrawArrays`.

Now, in your case inside the loop you render only a single quad, and the number of OpenGL calls is roughly the same with both methods. That's why you don't see a performance increase.

It seems that you can do this without any looping:

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(Vertex), &vert[0].x);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vert[0].u);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4 * sLen); // <-- note
```

thus rendering all the quads at once. I expect this to be a lot more performant.

An even better way (the one that is actually used in practice) is to use [VBO's](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object), thus copying vertex data on GPU only once and then using this.

Comment: Problem is at the moment with my code it is drawing just 1 char of the string at a time. i have used glDrawArrays to draw the full string at once once the verts are added but thats still slow

Comment: I dont think i can use VBO's because i dont know what the text will be.

Comment: @wihutamiz Unfortunatelly, it's hard to tell anything without the full code. OpenGL is verycomplex and different seemingly unrelated things can actually influence each other.
Concerning VBO's: I would expect the text not to change frequently, so you can just refill VBO with data upon text change.

Answer (score 1):

@lisyarus is correct. Your issue is that you're using a interfaces intended to work with a buffer object, but you are using it in a immediate mode method.

I saw in your comment to @lisyarus that you said you could not use buffer objects because you do not know your string in advance. However, this is not entirely true. I am going to make some assumptions below, which may or may not be correct, but they should point you in the correct direction.

In your current example you are sending a draw for each quad that represents a character in your string. Based on this we know, at minimum, how long this string is. Instead, lets build an in memory representation and then batch your draw commands to take care of all characters in your string.

So in the beginning create your in memory representation

```
Vertex* v = (Vertex*)malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * numOfVertexForString);
```

Then in your loop do not issue any `GL` function calls. Instead build out the memory buffer above. Then after your loop create a VBO and draw all of your quads in one single call.

```
GLuint vbo;
GLGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
GLBindBuffer(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, vbo);
GLBufferData(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, sizeof(Vertex) * numOfVertexInString, v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then, finally draw the content of the buffer object.

```
glDrawArray(GL_QUADS, 0, 4 * sLen);
```

When working with any graphics library the focus is on reducing the number of calls you make. Because these calls route through the driver they are slow. Even worst, is that if your data is not in the format the graphics library needs the driver if forced to translate it. You cannot avoid what goes on in the driver, but you can avoid the number of calls you send its way.